# Why my dumped hprof file show total heap only 9.6MB while the actually heap size is 75MB

Tags: java, profiling, hprof

I got a hprof file from the user who encounter a OutOfMemory exception. but when open that file with Eclipse Memory Analyzer, it show that total memory only 9.6MB far from the actual heap size 75MB. Is possible that profile process only dump part of heap space?

Comment: would help if you posted the exception

Answer (score 0):

MAT skips unreachable objects so doesnt report exact heap size.

[Details](http://wiki.eclipse.org/MemoryAnalyzer/FAQ#MAT_Does_Not_Show_the_Complete_Heap) will be useful for you.